# Notepad++ open cmd in current file's directory

Tags: windows-7, command-line, notepad++

Is there a way (probably a macro) how to open cmd in current file's directory?

Say I am editting a file `D:\foo\bar.txt` and would like to open cmd in `D:\foo\`. It would really help running various precompilers etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under the `Run` menu there is an option `Open current dir cmd` which does exactly what you want.

[image]

If your file is on a UNC path then this won't work as it's not possible to `cd` to a UNC on a command line.

If your source file is on a different drive letter than Notepad++ then it will switch to the correct path but won't switch the drive letter as it appears not to be adding the `/D` switch to the `cd` command. However, immediately entering `x:` <kbd>Enter</kbd> (where `x` is the drive letter where your source file is located) will switch you to the correct path.

You can make the `/D` default for this by editing the `shortcuts.xml` file in your user profile (on Win7 it is located in `D:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml`) and adding `/D` to the `Open current dir cmd` line:

```
<Command name="Open current dir cmd" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">cmd /K cd /D $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)</Command>
```

**NB:** You cannot edit this file using Notepad++ as it will be overwritten by the in memory options when Notepad++ is closed. Ensure there is no running Notepad++ and edit the xml file using MS Notepad or any other text editor.

(**EDIT:** Patch submitted to Notepad++ on SourceForge to correct this: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3475087&group_id=95717&atid=612384)

If you want to assign to a shortcut key select `Run` -> `Modify Shortcut/Delete Command...`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which unfortunatelly opens the notepad++ install path. See http://grab.by/bA2T. What could go wrong? I even tried to add the notepad++ folder to the PATH, but that didn't help.

Comment: Oh I see your edit and I can confim that on `drive_letter:` it changes the path correctly. Anyway, that's still odd. Is there a way how to make this work by default (probably edit the macro written somewhere deep in n++)? There would be no harm typing the drive_letter before each cd

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Strangely, `cmd /K cd /D $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)` doesn't work when in `shortcuts.xml`, while it does work in the shell itself. Dunno what's wrong...

Comment: you cannot edit `shortcuts.xml` using Notepad++ as it will be overwritten again with the in memory values when you exit Notepad++. ensure all Notepad++ are closed then edit using MS Notepad. Ensure you are updating the xml file in your user profile, not the one in the install dir.

Comment: I found a bug raised for this issue on sourceforge and have submitted a patch: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3475087&group_id=95717&atid=612384

Comment: it's a pleasure :)

Comment: I've updated the answer to include editing using MS Notepad.

Comment: Normally, I had this menu entries before, but in a freshly installed win8.1 instance and notepad++ 6.7 I had to use your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Run command has moved on later versions of Notepad++ to:
[Right click on file Tab. i.e. new 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwAHT.jpg) 
Select Open Containing Folder in cmd

Also, File->Open Containing Folder->cmd

Answer (score 1):

CMD can be opened in the current directory if you pass the arguments to CMD with the Notepad++ syntax:

```
<Command name="Open current folder in cmd" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="79">cmd /K &quot; cd /D $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY) &quot;</Command>
```