# wine notepad++ 'Open Containing Folder in cmd' set terminal

Tags: terminal, notepad++, cmd.exe, wine

I'd like to be able to open a folder in a different terminal that the one set by default by wine. Is it possible to modify this option?

Comment: I run NP++ on Wine and **Open Containing Folder** has a submenu of **Explorer** or **cmd**, both of which work, as they do when running in Windows. It's not clear what you would like do differently.

Comment: @AFH what I want is to use my own terminal, and not wine's terminal

Comment: You could try renaming `cmd.exe` and creating it as a link to your terminal, but I have no idea what will happen if your terminal doesn't run in `wine`. I don't know if the `cmd` [start-up file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404165/how-to-run-a-command-on-command-prompt-startup-in-windows) works in `wine`, but you may be able to use this to check if `cmd` has been launched from `notepad++` and launch your shell if so.

Comment: Since I've found Notepad++ just a bit flaky under wine, I've been using the native Kate. See if it meets your needs (though I do prefer Notepad++ for all its plugins).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find how to add custom terminal to the context menus (i.e. directory tree, Open Containg Folder or Open into), but you can add it to the Run menu by following this steps:

1. Close Notepad++;
2. Open this file in different editor:

   - `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml`;
3. Under the `<UserDefinedCommands>` add your own command, for example:

   - `<Command name="Open current folder in Terminal" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="79">wt.exe -d &quot;$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)&quot;</Command>`

---

Above command will open directory of currently active file in Windows Terminal (if it's installed), but you can modify it by your needs. Behaviour is undefined if you will use it when you don't have any opened text file in Notepad++. You can change shortcut under `Run -> Modify Shortcut... -> Run commands`.

This is how it will look like:
[Custom command in Run menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdiFD.png)

Also this answers are relevant: [1](https://superuser.com/a/379533/1742213), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43782826/20340543)